# How can i overlay one Button over another button

Tags: android, android-layout

i want  0 to 9 buttons in two row.Each button have overlay of another small button in right bottom corner.when i click the button,count will be displayed on overlay button.sorry for my bad english thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandable2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
      RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btn0"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/btn0"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="0" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

My output 
[image: https://program.dotfit.com/startprogram.aspx]

any other suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: you can use framelayout contains two buttons and use grid layout for all buttons, no need to make layout for all

Comment: A Button in a Button... What a **TERRIBLE UI** you are going to design.

Comment: yeah bro it's a terrible UI.....i am new to android where can learn about ui design completely

Comment: Use Google to search for tutorials. Or for UI design tips.

Comment: R u kidding me.........i want any specific websites to study about UI designs completly

Comment: No kidding. That's how you go. Googling is an important part of our job.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it like this

```
 android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a framelayout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/icon_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button                
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_goal_check" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

[image: Something like this]

After that you can reuse this layout for all your buttons. To reuse this in your xml, create a custom view as follows :

```
public class YourButton extends FrameLayout {

    private Button buttonOne, buttonTwo;

    public YourButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        initializeViews();
    }

    public YourButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.GoalButton);
        typedArray.recycle();
        initializeViews();
    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_button_layout, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        buttonOne = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
        buttonTwo = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.button_two);
    }

    public void setCount(String count){
        buttonTwo.setText(count);
    }
}
```

now you can use in your layout as

```
<yourPackageName.YourButton
      android:id="@+id/button_one"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This will keep your main layout simple and tidy.

Comment: you can use horizontal linear layout as you are using now

Answer (score 0):

Use a textview for showing the count because a button over a button is meaningless.
Anyways how to show it.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "60dp">

<Button 
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/btn"/>
<Button
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/countbtn"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight= "true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

use this view in your Grid or RecyclerView Adapter to make it 10 times as you wish to show.

incase you want to use TextView to show Count remove the `countBtn` and make it a textView with last two attributes same.

Comment: modify the width and height accordingly i kept it `match_parent` and `60dp` resp.